# Let $G$ Be a group and $K\subset H \subset G$. $H$ be a subgroup of $G$, $K$ be a subgroup of $H$. Prove that $K$ is a subgroup of $G$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> **Let $G$ Be a group and $K\subset H \subset G$.  $H$ be a subgroup of $G$, $K$ be a subgroup of $H$. Prove that $K$ is a subgroup of $G$. Assume that operations are always the same.**

Attempt:

Let $a, b\in K$ then as $K\subset H$ and $K$ is a subgroup of $H$ then $ab^{-1}\in K \subset H \subset G.$ then $ab^{-1}\in G$. Therefore, $K$ is a subgroup of $G$. Is this correct? If not please help me to correct.

Comment: $K$ is a subset of $G$ which is also a group. It has the same multiplication and identity as $G$ and is therefore a subgroup of $G$.

Comment: You are correct.

Comment: Your attempt is not fully correct, because you've shown $ab^{-1} \in G$, which is unnecessary and insufficient. Before that, you've shown that for $ab^{-1} \in K$, which is actually sufficient, provided you've proved that any subset is a subgroup iff it is non-empty and for all of its elements $a$ and $b$, $ab^{-1}$ is also its element.

Comment: @M.Vinay $K$ is surely non-empty as $K$ is a subgroup of $H$. So it is not necessary to show it again. Am I right.

Comment: @user1942348 You should start with the assumption that $K\subset G$ and then prove that $a,b\in K\implies ab^{-1}\in G.$

Comment: @user1942348 Right. See user160110's answer. What I want to be clear about is that you just have to have proved the basic result (subgroup condition) first, if you want to use that. Otherwise do what Zorngo said, which directly uses the definition: a subset that is itself a group under the same operation as that of the group (well, technically the restriction of the operation to the subset) is a subgroup.

Answer (score 2):

The definition of a subgroup $K$ of a group $G$ is that $K$ is a group and that $K\subseteq G$. Since $K$ is a subgroup of $H$ it must be a group and $H\subset G$, can you see how $K$ is a subgroup of $G$.

Your proof looks okay but the ordering is a bit weird. Start with the fact that $K\subset G$ and then prove that $a,b\in K\implies ab^{-1}\in K$. Which would be the end of your proof.